# How can I add a custom data field to my gridview while fetching database records in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am populating a grid in asp with results from a database table called Students.  The students table has columns of pointsEarned and pointsPossible.  I need to calculate the letter grade based on the percentage of pointsEarned / pointsPossible.  I do this in a class called Grades.  How do I get the values of pointsEarned and pointsPossible for the current student and then add the calculated letterGrade to the grid?

Here's my method:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstring;
            connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetStudents", conn);

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            conn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "dbo.Students");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("letterGrade", typeof(string));

            Grades studentGrade = new Grades();
            studentGrade.pointsEarned = ???;
            studentGrade.pointsPossible = ???;
            string studentLetterGrade = studentGrade.calculate();

            //How do I add studentLetterGrade as the letterGrade column?

            StudentGrid.DataSource = ds;
            StudentGrid.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
```

Here's my grid:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GetStudents" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConn %>" SelectCommand="dbo.GetStudents" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="StudentGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="studentId" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="firstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="semester" HeaderText="Semester" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="semesterYear" HeaderText="Year" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="letterGrade" HeaderText="Grade" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways of doing this, simplest of means would be to calculate the percentage in the db stored proc itself and retrieve and bind to grid.

else if you wish not to modify the current stored procedure and wish modify during binding from codebehind, you have to use gridview rowdatabound event, and bind all columns one by one and modify values based on condition if so required.

Comment: Yes, I could calculate the percentage in the query, but I also need to calculate the letter grade based on the percentage(A, B, C, D, F) which is done in my Grades class.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 - use the gridview rowdatabound event, this event will be fired when a data row is bound to data in a gridview control, this will allow you to modify data when binding to grid.. this will help you  to get started. [msdn rowdatabound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)